# RxJs: How to only maintain the latest value until inner observable complete

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, reactive

I'm new to RxJs and having trouble to achieve this in "RxJs way":

An infinite stream `a$` emits a value `a` once a while.

`async()` takes the `a` and performs an async operation.

If `a$` emits values while `async` is pending, only keep the latest one `al`.

After the previous `async` completes, if there is an `al`, run `async(al)`.

And so on.

```
a$:----a1----------a2----a3-----------------------a4-----------
       async(a1):------------end                  async(a4):---
                             async(a3):-----end
```

Here is what I came up with, a bit nasty:

```
var asyncIdle$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject()
var asyncRunning$ = new Rx.Subject()
var async$ = asyncIdle$

function async (val) {
  async$ = asyncRunning$
  // do something with val
  console.log(val + ' handling')
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(val + ' complete')
    async$.next()
    async$ = asyncIdle$
  }, 2000)
}

// simulate a$
var a$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
.mapTo(1)
.scan((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
.do(val => console.log('got ' + val))


a$.debounce(() => async$)
.subscribe(val => {
  async(val)
})
```

Comment: My gut reaction says that a ReplaySubject may be good for this, but I'll need to think about it more. Here's a link to ReplaySubject docs FWIW: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/ReplaySubject.js~ReplaySubject.html

Comment: @vincecampanale thanks! I'll look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`audit` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-audit) to solve the problem, like this (the comments should explain how it works):

```js
// Simulate the source.

const source = Rx.Observable.merge(
  Rx.Observable.of(1).delay(0),
  Rx.Observable.of(2).delay(10),
  Rx.Observable.of(3).delay(20),
  Rx.Observable.of(4).delay(150),
  Rx.Observable.of(5).delay(300)
).do(value => console.log("source", value));

// Simulate the async task.

function asyncTask(value) {
  return Rx.Observable
    .of(value)
    .do(value => console.log(" before async", value))
    .delay(100)
    .do(value => console.log(" after async", value));
}

// Compose an observable that's based on the source.
// Use audit to ensure a value is not emitted until
// the async task has been performed.
// Use share so that the signal does not effect a
// second subscription to the source.

let signal;

const audited = source
  .audit(() => signal)
  .mergeMap(value => asyncTask(value))
  .share();

// Compose a signal from the audited observable to
// which the async task is applied.
// Use startWith so that the first emitted value
// passes the audit.

signal = audited
  .mapTo(true)
  .startWith(true);

audited.subscribe(value => console.log("output", value));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but I think this solution is not correct. e.g. when I execute the code, I see this sequence: `before async 3`, `source 4`, `before async 4`, `after async 3`. I think that the async call `4` should be skipped, because async `3` is still in progress, right?

Comment: @TmTron I noticed that too. The most recent value from `audit` does not go through `audit` that's why the next new value is given a new audition.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution in typescript:

I have a simple `Gate` class that can be open or closed:

```js
enum GateStatus {
  open = "open",
  closed = "closed"
}

class Gate {
  private readonly gate$: BehaviorSubject<GateStatus>;

  readonly open$: Observable<GateStatus>;
  readonly closed$: Observable<GateStatus>;

  constructor(initialState = GateStatus.open) {
    this.gate$ = new BehaviorSubject<GateStatus>(initialState);
    this.open$ = this.gate$
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(filter(status => status === GateStatus.open));
    this.closed$ = this.gate$
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(filter(status => status === GateStatus.closed));
  }

  open() {
    this.gate$.next(GateStatus.open);
  }
  close() {
    this.gate$.next(GateStatus.closed);
  }
}
```

The operator function is quite simple. At the beginning the gate is open. Before we start a request, we close it and when the request has finished we open it again.
The `audit()` will only let the most recent request-data pass when the gate is open.

```js
export const requestThrottle = <T>(
  requestHandlerFactory: (requestData: T) => Observable<any>
) => (requestData: Observable<T>) => {
  const gate = new Gate();
  return requestData.pipe(
    audit(_ => gate.open$),
    // NOTE: when the order is important, use concatMap() instead of mergeMap()
    mergeMap(value => {
      gate.close();
      return requestHandlerFactory(value).pipe(finalize(() => gate.open()));
    })
  );
};
```

use it like this:

```js
src.pipe(
    requestThrottle(() => of(1).pipe(delay(100)))
);
```

[code exmaple on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uvsqdg?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 0):

#### A Solution With RxJS v6+ Primatives

Here's a solution that works in current RxJS versions (now available as the Node package [rxjs-audit-with](https://github.com/fivecar/rxjs-audit-with)):

```
export function auditWith<T, R>(
  callback: (value: T) => Promise<any>,
): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  const freeToRun = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  return (source: Observable<T>) => {
    return source.pipe(
      audit(_val => freeToRun.pipe(filter(free => free))),
      tap(() => freeToRun.next(false)),
      mergeMap(val => callback(val)),
      tap(() => freeToRun.next(true)),
    );
  };
}
```

#### How It Works

`auditWith` is an operator that uses a `BehaviorSubject` to track whether `callback` is busy. It uses `audit` to keep only the most recent value to come down the pipe, and releases that value the next time the `BehaviorSubject` is marked as free. `tap` goes before and after the async call in order to make it as busy/free (respectively), and `mergeMap` is used to actually call the async `callback`. Note that `callback` receives the latest value from the pipe, but can return anything it wants (if anything at all); the same value will propagate down the pipe unchanged (by design).

#### An Example of Use

```
async function slowFunc(num: number) {
  await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Processed num", num);
      resolve(true);
    }, 3000),
  );
}

interval(500)
  .pipe(
    take(13),
    auditWith(slowFunc),
  )
  .subscribe();

// Sample output:
// Processed num 0
// Processed num 5
// Processed num 11
// Processed num 12
```

Even though sequential numbers are generated by `interval` every 500ms, `auditWith` will hold the latest value in the pipe until `slowFunc` has returned from its previous iteration. Note that the very first value is guaranteed to be run (because the async function is assumed to start in the "available" state), and the last value in the Observable is also guaranteed to run (i.e. the pipe will drain).

Answer (score -1):

use a combination of `first()` and `repeat()`. if `a$` finished emission the sequence complete

```js
//emit every 1s
const a$=new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0)
Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(100).skip(1).subscribe(a$);

// //simulate aysnc 
const async = (val)=>{
  console.log('async start with:'+ val)
  return Rx.Observable.timer(5100).mapTo('async done:'+val);
}

a$.first().switchMap(value=>async(value))
  .repeat()
  .catch(e=>Rx.Observable.empty())
  .subscribe(console.log,console.err,console.warn)

a$.subscribe(console.warn)
```

https://jsbin.com/tohahod/65/edit?js,console

Comment: Wouldn't it run repeatedly forever even when a$ doesn't emit new value?

Comment: I meant the `async`

Comment: if your a$ is hot observable, a$.take(1) will only give you the latest if there's isn't any it will not emit.something like Observable.fromEvent('click',a).take(1) won't emit if there's no click

Comment: Oh, what I meant is when a$ stop emitting new values, wouldn't `async` still keep running?

Comment: Maybe i can test it out

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that I've tested it before asking you. I use `const a$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(2).share()` to stop `a$`, and `async` still keep running. I think the problem is `example` repeatedly takes the latest value from a$, but not knowing if that value is processed or not.

Comment: run into the same problem too. I am working on a fix

Comment: Still not quite right. If `a$` emits new values during `async`, it just ignored the latest value.

Comment: It does always take the latest value from a$ and emit only when async complete no?

Comment: Take the graph in the question for example, `a$` emits `a2` and `a3` during `async(a1)`. When `async(a1)` is finished, the latest value of `a$` is `a3`, which has not been processed, hence perform `async(a3)`.

Comment: You can try out the jsBin it does what the graph says.a$ gives 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 emit for every second till 10 , first taken is value:0 then after 5 second async () process 6 as parameter

Comment: 0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    value:0
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    value:5

Comment: If you log out the values you can see it takes the next value rather than the previous latest value. So if `a$` goes idle, `async` won't be invoked.

Comment: `0 1 2 3 4 value:0 5 6 7 8 9 value:5`, `value:5` should be `value:4`

Comment: argh, you want to keep the last latest during async i see.

Comment: Edited the answer used behaviorSubject can fullfill your requirement.

Comment: This only works, when the async-duration (5100) is higher than the input-duration (100). Otherwise it will always repeat the previous value...